# Java stack using 2 queue

Tags: java, recursion, tree, stack, queue

Hi im trying to implement stack using queue and im getting exeption for some reason.

im getting exeption on run when im try to push some integer
hope some one could tell me why isempty now working with this main:
this is my implemetion:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class StackWithQueue {
       ArrayBlockingQueue <Integer> queue1;
       ArrayBlockingQueue <Integer> queue2;
       int size;
       // class constructor
    public StackWithQueue(int size){
        this.size = size;
        this.queue1 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
        this.queue1 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
    }
    // push element into the stack
    public void push(int val){
         if(this.isEmpty()){
                queue1.offer(val);
            }else{
                if(queue1.size()>0){
                    queue2.offer(val);
                    int size = queue1.size();
                    while(size>0){
                        queue2.offer(queue1.poll());
                        size--;
                    }
                }else if(queue2.size()>0){
                    queue1.offer(val);
                    int size = queue2.size();
                    while(size>0){
                        queue1.offer(queue2.poll());
                        size--;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    public int pop(){
        int val = 0;
          if(queue1.size()>0){
               val = queue1.poll();
            }else if(queue2.size()>0){
               val =  queue2.poll();
            }
          return val;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return this.queue1.isEmpty() & this.queue2.isEmpty();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 5;
        StackWithQueue sq = new StackWithQueue(5);
        for (int i = 0; i <=size ; i++) {
            sq.push(i);
        }
        while(!sq.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(sq.pop()+",");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo error:

```
    this.queue1 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
    this.queue1 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
```

Replace it with:

```
    this.queue1 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
    this.queue2 =  new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(size);
```